# Cannot install node.js under Windows 7: "the specified path is too long"

Tags: windows-7, installation, node.js

Using the newest node.js installer from https://nodejs.org, I run into the same error every time when it reaches the npm installation. npm 3.x was supposed to deal with this issue, but apparently it doesn't help the node.js installer. The node developers have essentially refused to do anything about it, as this problem has been around for about two years already. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a work around. How can I get this to install?

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit. What path are you trying to install to? (I used `c:\apps\nodejs`)

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried your suggestion, and also even installing it in c:\n, but that didn't help either. I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ultimate shouldn't make a difference. Are you installing as an admin? Is the title the complete error message?

Comment: I'm installing as admin. The full text of the error is "The specified path is too long: C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules\test\fixtures\a"

Comment: I'll bet the answer is nothing to do with a file path but instead it is complaining about your system PATH environment variable.

Comment: See my answer [Why does Windows have a limit on environment variables at all?](//superuser.com/a/1070354)

Comment: By the way, please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: The longest file path generated by my install is 172 characters which is way under the limit of 260 characters.

Comment: @Fibericon No issues installing Node here on several Windows 7, 8, and 10 boxes, and no issues with NPM packages lately due to the way the paths are set up.

Answer (score -2):

This might happen, when you install nodejs (or its component) in a very long  path, like this:

```
c:\something_folder_blabla\another_folder_longname\another_still_folder\something_folder_blabla\another_folder_longname\another_still_folder\.............................nodejs\
```

or unicode(UTF-8) chars containing path:

```
c:\სპეციალცჰარაქტერს\\another_folder\nodejs
```

So, install in a shorter and English-charactered path

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have much to do with my question. This is just a generic response to path length issues, that doesn't tackle the problem with node and npm at all.